# Alert Notification in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, notifications, uialertview

In my app I want to show an alert like user came online.. went offline.. like that. I tried with UIAlertView, but its kind of bigger in size than what I wanted. I am new to IOS, I have explored in stack overflow also didn't got exact solution. Anyone give an idea.. what kind of notification I have to show for this case.

Need: Notification without smaller in size without ok button, should hide automatically after few seconds. (e.g.: Toast message in Android)

thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965417/ios-push-notification-alert-is-not-shown-when-the-app-is-running

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html

Comment: do you have pattern to catch the actions on which you want to show the alert?

Comment: @All I need to show when my app is active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple didn't provide any build in API's I guess to behave like toasted messages in Android.

Answer (score 2):

Check out a library like [AJNotificationView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ajnotificationview)

[image]

or [JSNotifier](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jsnotifier)

[image]

or HUD libraries like SVStatusHUD or MBProgressHUD

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to show a small alert with a message, then you can do it like this:

```
UIAlertView *doneAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
UILabel *lblText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 300, 22)];
lblText.text = @"User came Online\n";
lblText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f];
lblText.numberOfLines = 2;
lblText.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
lblText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lblText.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
lblText.center = CGPointMake(140, 45);
[doneAlert addSubview:lblText];
[doneAlert show];
```

It will show a small alert box with a message only.

Edit:

Autohide like this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(closeAlert) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Then method `closeAlert`

```
-(void)closeAlert {
    [doneAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Do we autohide it after few seconds?

Comment: Yes, after this code I set a timer for 1 second, which fires a method and that method dismisses the alert, so you'll have to take the alert object global.

Comment: One more question-When we use UIAlertview background is going dark like inactive and focus will come to UIAlertview.. in real time many people will go online, offline, frequent showing will not look good I think, any idea?

Comment: That's true, it is not feasible to show pop up like this every time any user comes online or goes offline, for that you can just add a button for each user, in the list. Beside the name of the user, if user comes online, change the button color to green, or else keep some other color. Or you can use anything in place of button.

Comment: Can you please correct my answer, if it was a true solution to your problem, so that it can be useful for others too. thanks...

Comment: Ya I'm already doing this in Address book, apart from this I need user should come to know by alert.

Answer (score 1):

You could try out [ALAlertBanner](https://github.com/alobi/ALAlertBanner). It's a project I just finished. It has tap to dismiss, auto-hide, and a couple other nice features.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: ALAlertBanner]