# push notification when open app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have push notification in my app and all work if app is close or app in background, but if app is run (active) push notification not show, but call method `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`

Comment: i want to show notification, when active app, its possible?

Comment: It's up to you whether to show alert or not while application is active (you should better parse the user info and do what you need without any alerts)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS - Push notification alert is not shown when the app is running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965417/ios-push-notification-alert-is-not-shown-when-the-app-is-running)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7965961/869455

When app is open, it's app's responsibility to handel notification appropriately in application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: and show a message to user inside app.

Answer (score 4):

You can tell whether your app was just brought to the foreground or not in didReceiveRemoteNotification using this bit of code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive )
        // app was already in the foreground
    else
        // app was just brought from background to foreground
    ...
}
```

You do not get to choose at delivery time what presentation method is used to present the push notification, that is encoded in the notification itself (optional alert, badge number, sound). But since you presumably are in control of both the app and the payload of the push notification, you can specify in the payload whether or not there was an alert view and message already presented to the user. Only in the case of the app is already running in the foreground do you know that the user did not just launch your app through an alert or regularly from the home screen.