# Notification popup in foreground

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification

I want to display notification popup when app is in foreground state, with alertbody as per code snippets. 
It is completely working when app is in background state.

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (notification == nil)
    return;
NSDate *dt = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:10 sinceDate:[NSDate date]];
notification.fireDate = dt;
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

notification.alertBody = @"After 10Secs...";
notification.alertAction = @"View";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Comment: I assume you know that when app is in foreground state the notification is received in applicationDidReceiveLocalNotification method(not sure about name of method though), from there you can show an alert

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23365259/2518805 if want to show notification like banner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`application:didreceiveLocalNotification`** method in your app delegate if you want to see the nofication while your app is in the foreground:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    //simply show a alert,but the standard one will not show up by itself
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyAlertView"
        message:notification.alertBody
        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    if (alertView) {
        [alertView release];
    }
}
```