# how to show push notification in foreground in ios?

Tags: ios, xcode6, apple-push-notifications, uialertview

my  app had a push notifications , can i show the push notification message in alert ?

NOTE:When user click on the notification  it will redirect to  the  application page and notification disappears so here show total notification  message in an alert? Is it possible in iOS application?

Comment: I partially understand your question , it is possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get push notification while App in foreground iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872088/get-push-notification-while-app-in-foreground-ios)

Answer (score 0):

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
  didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
  {

  NSString *stringNotify = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"] valueForKey:@"body"]];

  NSLog(@"the dictionary is %@",userInfo);

  UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notification"
                                                          message:stringNotify  delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
      [alertView show];

}

Answer (score 0):

I have created a custom Notification, which will help you to show notification when your app is in foreground.
Check the following link [iOSForegroundNotification](https://github.com/Kadasiddha/iOSForeGroundNotification)  and follow the steps given below:

1. Copy `SNotificationView.h` and `SNotificationView.m` in files in your project.
2. If you are using swift then add `#import "SNotificationView.h"` to your `Bridging-Header.h` file.
3. Copy "Glass.mp3" file for the notification sound.
4. You have replace/add you appicon image to "image.png".
5. You have add the following lines in your AppDelegate file:

   ```
   let settings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()
     if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
       if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {


           if let message = alert["message"] as? NSString {

               prefs.setObject(message, forKey: "notification")
               prefs.synchronize()
               print("Message: \( message)\n")
           }
       } else if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSString {

           // Push notification message is added in NSUserDefault
           prefs.setObject(alert, forKey: "notification")
           prefs.synchronize()

         if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active ) {

            if settings?.types & UIUserNotificationType.Alert != nil {
                   // .Alert is one of the valid options
                  // If you want to add the badge add the line below

                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1

                   //Call the custom Notification

                   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("remotenotification", object: nil)

               }
               else
               {
                   // This part will be called if you app notification is set to "NONE"
                   print("No alert   ")
               }
            }
       }
   ```
6. Add the following function for all your ViewController

   ```
   func callNotification()
   {
       let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
       let alert = prefs.stringForKey("notification")!

       SNotificationView.showNotificationViewWithImage(UIImage(named:"image.png"), title: "XcodeProject", message: alert, isAutoHide: true, onTouch: {        
       SNotificationView.hideNotificationViewOnComplete(nil)

       })
   }
   ```
7. Add the following line in your `viewDidLoad`

   ```
      NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "callNotification", name: "remotenotification", object: nil)
   ```

Hope this might be helpful