# How to receive an ios notification when in foreground?

Tags: ios, swift

I can receive the push notification in background, closed or in locked screen(my token,push server are OK). But when the app is running, I cannot get any notification or alert. Should I use `func didReceiveRemoteNotification` ?(in fact, this func cannot worked at all)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get push notification while App in foreground iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872088/get-push-notification-while-app-in-foreground-ios)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:sApplicationName message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]]delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alertView show];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Snippets from [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) :

**The notification is delivered when the app isn’t running in the foreground.** The system presents the notification, displaying an alert, badging an icon, perhaps playing a sound, and perhaps displaying one or more action buttons for the user to tap.

**The notification is delivered when the app is running in the foreground.** The app calls the UIApplicationDelegate method application:didReceiveLocalNotification: or application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:. (If application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: isn’t implemented, the system calls application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:.)

So you need handle the notification yourself when received foreground.
[This(Get push notification while App in foreground iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872088/get-push-notification-while-app-in-foreground-ios) may be helpful to you.