# Swift 3 - Firebase Push Notification, How can I do?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-notifications

I do like below in Swift 2. But It's not working in Swift 3. How Can I provide this? If someone explain this It would be great.

**didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

and

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
    if notificationSettings.types != .None {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    print("Meesage ID \(userInfo["gcm_message_id"]!)")
    print(userInfo)

}
```

I can do simple local notification but, I couldn't remote push notification from Firebase.

> I tried

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self

UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions([.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]) { (success, error:NSError?) in

        if success {
            print("Notification access true!")
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
        else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }

}
```

and

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    print("Meesage ID \(userInfo["gcm_message_id"]!)")
    print(userInfo)

}
```

still doesn't work.

Comment: The name of the delegate methods have changed slightly. By typing the name of each method, you should see corresponding method in Swift 3 as a suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The AppDelegate method names have changed a little and UserNotifications framework has been introduced. You must use this framework for notifications in iOS 10 and above as the other methods are being deprecated.

```
import UserNotifications

...

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    ...

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> ()) {

        print("Message ID \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")
        print(userInfo)
    }

    ...
}
```

[Registering for Push Notifications in Xcode 8/Swift 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956482/registering-for-push-notifications-in-xcode-8-swift-3-0)

Answer (score 1):

It is very important to remember that there may be different devices that run different versions of the iOS, and they may have different notification capabilities. I understand that the previous answer does point in the right direction.

We need to `import FirebaseInstanceID`, if we are to receive instance, or event based notifications. Such notifications are like the ones that pop-up when someone retweets our post, or likes a post, or a message notification.

However, if someone is looking for the complete code that goes into the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function in `AppDelegate`, here it is:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    FIRApp.configure()

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
           UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions(
            authOptions, completionHandler: {_,_ in })
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
    selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
    name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification,
    object: nil)

    return true
}

  func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
               fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
// This is required if you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background, which is the most common case!!

print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

print("%@", userInfo)
}


func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
  print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
}

connectToFcm()
}


func connectToFcm() {
FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
  if (error != nil) {
    print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
  } else {
    print("Connected to FCM.")
  }
 }
}
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
connectToFcm()
}
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
print("Disconnected from FCM.")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me Xcode 8, Swift 3.

**Inside didFinishLaunchingwithOptions func in AppDelegate.swift**

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {granted, error in
                    print(granted)
            })

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        FIRApp.configure()

        // [START set_messaging_delegate]
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
        // [END set_messaging_delegate]
```

**And the Delegates required to receive notifications from firebase:**

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

        // Print full message.
        print("%@", userInfo)

        let aps = userInfo["aps"] as! [String: Any]
        let notificationMessage = aps["alert"] as! String // processed content from notificaton

    }

}

extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)

    }
}
```