# Push notification is not receiving in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using `FCM` for push notification. `FCM` is connected, device is registered successfully and I am able to print device token but the device is not receiving notification. 
In general -> capabilities tab -> enabled push notification and remote notification in back ground mode.

Here registering device for remote notification.

```
  func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data
    ) {

    let trimEnds:String! = {
        deviceToken.description.trimmingCharacters(
            in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "<>"))
    }()


    let cleanToken:String! = {
        trimEnds.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    }()

    let token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
    print(token)

    UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "deviceToken")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    #if DEBUG
    //For Firebase
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
    #else
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.prod)
    #endif

    print("Device Token:", token)


}
```

Here I called `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method to receive notification on the registered device:

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    print("-=-=-=-=-\nDid receive notification\n-=-=-=-",userInfo)
    print("-=-=-=-=-\n")

       NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "notification_recieved"), object: nil)

    if userInfo.index(forKey: "chat_id") != nil {
        print("messag push")
        if (AppUtility?.hasValidText(User.userID))! {
            //let friendImage = userInfo["path"] as! String
            let chatID = userInfo["chat_id"] as! String
            let friendId = userInfo["to"] as! String
            let unRead = userInfo["unread"] as! String
            print(unRead)
            UnReadMsgs = unRead

            let dictAPS = userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary
            let dict = dictAPS["alert"] as! NSDictionary
            let friendName = dict["title"] as! String
            let friendMsg = dict["body"] as! String

            if(UIApplication.shared.applicationState == UIApplicationState.active){

                print("app is Active")
                if let wd = self.window {
                    var VC = wd.rootViewController
                    if(VC is UINavigationController){
                        VC = (VC as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController
                        if(VC is ChatViewController!){
                            print("Chat Screen")
                            let chatVC : ChatViewController = VC as! ChatViewController
                            if chatVC.chatId == chatID{
                                print("Same Chat")
                                self.clearChatWithChatID(chatID)
                            }else{
                                CustomNotificationView.showNotificationPopUp(self.window!, name: friendName, msg: friendMsg, image: "", chat: chatID, friendID: friendId)

                                playSound()
                                print("Other Chat")
                            }
                        }else{
                            let nc = NotificationCenter.default
                            nc.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "MessageGet"),
                                                    object: nil,
                                                    userInfo: ["unRead":unRead,
                                                        "date":Date()])
                            CustomNotificationView.showNotificationPopUp(self.window!, name: friendName, msg: friendMsg, image: "", chat: chatID, friendID: friendId)

                            playSound()
                            print("Other Screen")
                        }
                    }
                }

            }else{

                print("app is in BG")

                var vc:ChatViewController!
                vc = ChatViewController(nibName: "ChatViewController", bundle: nil)
                vc.chatId = chatID
                vc.otherUserId = friendId
                vc.otherUserName = friendName
                vc.channelRef = self.channelRef.child("\(chatID)")
                vc.friendImageLink = "\(resourceUrl)\("")"

                let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                nav.isNavigationBarHidden = false

                if let wd = self.window {
                    var VC = wd.rootViewController
                    if(VC is UINavigationController){
                        VC = (VC as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController
                    }


                    VC!.present(nav, animated: false, completion: {
                    })

                }


            }


        }

    }else{
        let val = userInfo["aps"] as! [String:AnyObject];
        let alert  =   NSString(string: val["alert"] as! String)
        if(UIApplication.shared.applicationState == UIApplicationState.inactive || UIApplication.shared.applicationState == UIApplicationState.background)
        {
            showUserInfo(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo)
                      }
        else
        {

            print("top most vc \(String(describing: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!.topMostViewController().presentingViewController)) and presentedvc \(String(describing: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!.topMostViewController().presentedViewController))")

            if UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!.topMostViewController() is NYAlertViewController{

                let newAlert = AppUtility?.getDisplayAlertController(title: "FitFlow", messageText: alert as String)
                let nvVc = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!.topMostViewController().presentedViewController
                nvVc?.present(newAlert!, animated: true, completion: nil)

                return

            }

                AppUtility?.displayAlert(title:"FitFlow", messageText: alert as String,UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!.topMostViewController())




        }

    }
}
```

I have tested by keeping breakpoints, it does not called `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method at all. How to receive push notification using above method?

Comment: what does your payload look like? Do you have notifications enabled on the device? Are you testing on device or simulator?

Comment: if your `didReceiveRemoteNotification` isn't getting called at all then kindly delete all its code block until you find out why it's not getting hit. I mean the rest of the code isn't necessary to see to help.

Comment: @Honey Hey still could not able to find solution for this ???  any idea

Comment: Hello PvDev, have you tested notification through Firebase console?

Comment: @MannamBrahmam nope!!..

Comment: Can you try to send notification from Firebase console instead of your server? and then let me know, you are receiving notification from firebase or not..

Comment: -generate APNs key.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs
-upload APNs key to firebase project.
in firebase project => settings => cloud messaging => iOS app configuration => APNs Authentication Key
-also Make sure your application requested notification permissions upon first launch.

  // requests permissions from the user
  FCM.requestPermissions();
  FCM.getToken()

Comment: @MannamBrahmam I have already done this

Comment: Don't you think, adding bounty when you haven't already tried/replied to the comments is useless.

Comment: Can you share the payload?

Comment: @PvDev did you set delegate ?

Comment: @PvDev Please follow steps from this url https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Comment: Please consider adding the FCM tag to this question and defining the acronym (any acronym) the first time you use it. Thanks.

Comment: make breakpoint to didReceiveRemoteNotification with fetchCompletionHandler and check if it is getting called or not?

Comment: can I know to whom you are working with production certificate or development certificate for push notification?

Comment: Does requesting authorization to display notifications make a difference?

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
       .requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
           // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
}


Also, would you be able to implement

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) { ... }
to see if there's any error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39434093/swift-3-firebase-push-notification-how-can-i-do Please go through this link... some methods are deprecated

Comment: @PvDev have you upload .p12 file in firebase console

Comment: @PvDev Please check my answer and confirm if that works for you?

Answer (score 3):

I was also stuck with this earlier.

This requires **FCM token**, and not the **APNS token**.

> To do so,
> Your AppDelegate class needs to have these -

```
import Firebase
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging

class AppDelegate: UIResponder,
                   UIApplicationDelegate,
                UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate,
                FIRMessagingDelegate {
                
                }
```

> - Then subscribe the messaging delegate in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID =
    "Your client id"
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        FIRApp.configure()
    }
    
    FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self


    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]){ (granted, error) in }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
        // iOS 9 support
    else if #available(iOS 9, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
        // iOS 8 support
    else if #available(iOS 8, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
        // iOS 7 support
    else {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications(matching: [.badge, .sound, .alert])
    }
    

    return true
}
```

// You dont need didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method anymore

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) { }
```

> the token you received from the delegate `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is not useful,
>
> You need to use the **FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()**

Add below code in your applicationDidBecomeActive, this will check for FCM token refreshes, and handle that elegantly.

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:
        #selector(tokenRefreshNotification), name:
        NSNotification.Name.firInstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)
}

@objc func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(refreshedToken, forKey: "deviceToken")
        self.sendFCMTokenToServer(token: refreshedToken)
    }
    /* 
    Connect to FCM since connection may
    have failed when attempted before having a token.
    */
    else { 
        connectToFcm()
    }
}

func updatePushNotificationWebservice() {
    /*
     if you want to save that token on your server 
     Do that here.
     else use the token any other way you want.
    */
}

func connectToFcm() {
     
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(String(describing: error))")                   
            }
            else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
                /*
                **this is the token that you have to use**
                print(FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!)
                if there was no connection established earlier,
                you can try sending the token again to server.
                */

                let token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!
                self.sendFCMTokenToServer(token: token)

            }
        }
}
```

For debugging use the token obtained from `FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!`, and use the push notification firebase console with same token in the >project>Cloud messaging tab.

https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/

Answer (score -2):

Setting priority to high from backend solves my problem.

Please check from firebase console->cloud messaging(down left item) to send push notification.