# Get the push notification token - iOS 10, Swift 3

Tags: push-notification, notifications, swift3, ios10

How to get the device token from new **xCode 8**, **Swift 3** in **iOS 10**?

Here is the code to register notification:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {    

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegister notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {

    if notificationSettings.types != UIUserNotificationType() {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}
```

Here i get the token, but i get the following error

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafePointer<CChar>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeRawPointer)':
```

---

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    let chars = UnsafePointer<CChar>((deviceToken as NSData).bytes)
    var token = ""

    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
        token += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [chars[i]])
    }

    print("Registration succeeded!")
    print("Token: ", token)
}
```

Can anyone help me solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956482/registering-for-push-notifications-in-xcode-8-swift-3-0

Comment: You can follow this link its in objective C but you can get some idea
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572897/ios-10-push-notification-issue-solved

Answer (score 38):

This method may solve your problem in iOS 10 and greater:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    var token = ""
    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
        token = token + String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
    }
    print(token)
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote. But perhaps because there is no explanation for why/how `Data` needs to be converted to a `String` like this

Answer (score 12):

```
var pushToken = String(format: "%@", deviceToken as CVarArg)
pushToken = pushToken.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "<>"))
pushToken = pushToken.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3 example taken from [raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started).

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data){
    let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data -> String in
        return String(format: "%02.2hhx", data)
    }  
    let token = tokenParts.joined()
    print(token)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

One line:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let apnsDeviceToken = deviceToken.map {String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0)}.joined()
}
```

[From this tutorial.](https://medium.com/@scottlydon18/how-to-set-up-remote-push-notifications-for-ios-c44c180d1990)

Or a modular/encapsulated/OOP way:

```
extension Data {
  var string: String {
    return map {String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0)}.joined()
  }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
let token = deviceToken.string
```

Answer (score 3):

The below snnipet is working with Eric Aya solution :

```
let token = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
```

Thanks for all help :)

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same problem, this is the only thing that helped me:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let token = String(format: "%@", deviceToken as CVarArg)
        .trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "<>"))
        .replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Working Code for getting push notification token - iOS 11 or greater, Swift 4**

**Request user permission**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert,UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
    let pushNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationTypes, categories: nil)

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotificationSettings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true        
}
```

**Getting device token**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    let token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
    print(token) 
}
```

**In case of error**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {

    print("i am not available in simulator \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could work:

```
let chars = UnsafePointer<CChar>((deviceToken as NSData).bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to:CChar.self))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Code from Mixpanel library**

```
    let tokenChars = (deviceToken as NSData).bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: CChar.self)
    var tokenString = ""
    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
        tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you may need this token in different methods (like firebase, web engage, branch, etc), you can use a custom class to initial an APNS from the data containing both `data` and `string`

```
public class APNS {
    public init(deviceToken data: Data) {
        self.data = data
        self.string = data.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) } .joined()
    }

    public let data: Data
    public let string: String
}
```

then you can use it anywhere you need:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let token = APNS(deviceToken: deviceToken)
    print(token.string)
}
```