# Push notifications suddenly not being received

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

My device suddenly stopped receiving push notifications from my app, despite it working just a few minutes before.

- the device has granted notification permissions, the APNS certificate is still valid, and push notifications are enabled in xcode under Signing and Capabilities
- `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is being run, and my device is sending its token to my server
- My server is sending the notification bundle, including my token, to Apple when it should.

Here is my `AppDelegate`:

```
import UserNotifications

 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    ...

    registerForPushNotifications()

    return true
}

func registerForPushNotifications() {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    .requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
      [weak self] granted, error in

      print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
      guard granted else { return }
      self?.getNotificationSettings()
    }
}

func getNotificationSettings() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
        print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
        guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }
    let token = tokenParts.joined()
    print("Device Token: \(token)")
    global_device_token = token
}
```

None of the above has changed from when it was working just a few minutes ago. The only that that has changed is that multiple device tokens were sent to my server, which is now sending all of those tokens to Apple. I have tried deleting the app and reinstalling, disabling wifi, and restarting my device. This is on both an iPhone 8 and 8 Plus, running iOS 13.4

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51667590/10150796 this

Comment: The code in that answer is functionally the same as what I already have, and still doesn't work.

Comment: How did you get this fixed? The same thing happened to me. It was working fine until it totally stopped