# Not getting the APNS token from iOS

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I am using Firebase for Push Notification in my Flutter App. I didn't receive any  APNS token from iOS. Whether the IOS simulator provides an APNS token or not or if it requires a Physical Device.
AppDelegate.swift code.

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import UserNotifications
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
           let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

           center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
               if error == nil{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
               }
           }

       }
       else {
           UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil))
           UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
       }
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you also add push notification capability?

Comment: Yes Added. In Android Device Push Notifications Works fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47386207/getting-remote-notification-device-token-in-swift-4

Comment: Tell me one more thing whether the IOS simulator provides an APNS token or not or if it requires a Physical Device.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test registering remote notification on real device, if you run on simulator ou will get this error: "[0]   (null)  "NSLocalizedDescription" : **"remote notifications are not supported in the simulator"**.

Comment: Also I want to know that APNS token also generated on Real Device??

Comment: I ran my project on real device vs on simulator. On real device, the APN token was generated, on simulator APN token was not generated and ended with above error

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm what Mr.SwiftOak said, you can use the getAPNSToken function only on a real iOS device, otherwise it will return null on simulators.

Answer (score 0):

you must need to run in device . because simulator not provide the token it will retunrn null value.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31177387)