# swift 3.0 Data to String?

Tags: swift, string

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {}
```

I want `deviceToken` to string

but:

```
let str = String.init(data: deviceToken, encoding: .utf8)
```

`str` is `nil`

swift 3.0

how can I let `data` to `string` ?

[Registering for Push Notifications in Xcode 8/Swift 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956482/registering-for-push-notifications-in-xcode-8-swift-3-0)
not working and the answer is a few months ago, I had tried it:

[image]

and print:

[image]

Comment: Next time you ask someone to try out your code make sure it's not pasted as image..

Comment: If someone comes across this when reading a file, check that the file is UTF8 encoded: `file -I /path/to/file.txt`. If not convert using iconv: `iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 /path/to/file.txt > /path/to/utf8/file.txt`

Answer (score 169, accepted):

I came looking for the answer to the Swift 3 Data to String question and never got a good answer. After some fooling around I came up with this:

```
var testString = "This is a test string"
var somedata = testString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
var backToString = String(data: somedata!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String!
```

Comment: I had try you answer. It's worked in other func, but not working in `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)`.I do not know why?

Comment: the device token is not a utf8 string, it is raw binary

Comment: so what to do if it is raw binary?

Comment: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue -- for anyone in the latest Swift

Comment: for decoding token using didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956482/registering-for-push-notifications-in-xcode-8-swift-3-0

Answer (score 39):

here is my data extension. add this and you can call data.ToString()

```
import Foundation

extension Data
{
    func toString() -> String?
    {
        return String(data: self, encoding: .utf8)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very bad coding - you should never force unwrap this since the encoding can always fail and this would crash the app. Instead return an optional string like the Apple API does for very good reasons.

Comment: @WalterWhite yeah in the application i return optional string. but not update this answer, thanks for the comment

Comment: If you pass encoding as a parameter, maybe default it to .utf8 if you like, you can then use this for more than a single encoding type.

Answer (score 19):

```
let str = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
```

Answer (score 7):

I found the way to do it. You need to convert `Data` to `NSData`:

```
let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "<>")
let nsdataStr = NSData.init(data: deviceToken)
let deviceStr = nsdataStr.description.trimmingCharacters(in: characterSet).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
print(deviceStr)
```

Comment: which characterSet is this ?

Comment: Let's avoid using NSData with Swift.

Comment: Don't use this method. It's unsafe.

Answer (score 2):

This is much easier in Swift 3 and later using reduce:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let token = deviceToken.reduce("") { $0 + String(format: "%02x", $1) }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { 
        let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/myApp/apns.php")!

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: [
            "token" : token, 
            "ios" : UIDevice.current.systemVersion,
            "languages" : Locale.preferredLanguages.joined(separator: ", ")
            ])

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request).resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4 version of 4redwings's answer:

```
let testString = "This is a test string"
let somedata = testString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
let backToString = String(data: somedata!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `let data = String(decoding: myStr, as: UTF8.self)` here is a resource about [converting data to string](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/146/how-to-update-your-code-to-modern-swift)

Answer (score 1):

for swift 5

```
let testString = "This is a test string"
let somedata = testString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
let backToString = String(data: somedata!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String?
print("testString > \(testString)")
//testString > This is a test string
print("somedata > \(String(describing: somedata))")
//somedata > Optional(21 bytes)
print("backToString > \(String(describing: backToString))")
//backToString > Optional("This is a test string")
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend on the answer of weijia.wang:

```
extension Data {
    func hexString() -> String {
        let nsdataStr = NSData.init(data: self)
        return nsdataStr.description.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "<>")).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    }
}
```

use it with `deviceToken.hexString()`

Answer (score 0):

According to the Apple doc below, device token can not be decoded. So, I think the best thing to do is just leave it be.

> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html
>
> Security Architecture
>
> A device token is an opaque NSData instance that contains a unique identifier assigned by Apple to a specific app on a specific device. Only APNs can decode and read the contents of a device token. Each app instance receives its unique device token when it registers with APNs, and must then forward the token to its provider, as described in Configuring Remote Notification Support. The provider must include the device token in each push notification request that targets the associated device; APNs uses the device token to ensure the notification is delivered only to the unique app-device combination for which it is intended.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is base64 encoded.

```
if ( dataObj != nil ) {
    let encryptedDataText = dataObj!.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions())
    NSLog("Encrypted with pubkey: %@", encryptedDataText)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let urlString = baseURL + currency

    if let url = URL(string: urlString){
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)        
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url){ (data, reponse, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error)
                return
            }


            let dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
            print(dataString)

        }

        task.resume()

    }
```