# UIUserNotificationSettings deprecated in iOS 10

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications, ios10, xcode8

I am looking for the alternate way of implementing UIUserNotificationSettings in iOS 10.

Apple documentation has given the below framework for the further usage. UNNotificationSettings in the link [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationsettings).

Is there any one who can help me with the sample code to implement the below using the UNNotificationSettings instead of UIUserNotificationSettings

```
let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(
        forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```

Comment: Sorry I just found the answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956482/registering-for-push-notifications-in-xcode-8-swift-3-0

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Registration of notification you should implement this code :

```
import UserNotifications

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { 
 (granted, error) in
 //Parse errors and track state
}
```

This [resource](https://swifting.io/blog/2016/08/22/23-notifications-in-ios-10/) contains additional information.

Comment: Do not forget to `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()` below this code.

Comment: @iOS.Wolf this is only necessary if you plan on having push notifications that aren't just local notifications.

Comment: Also don't forget to link with UserNotifications.framework and @import UserNotifications.

Comment: great tip to link with link with UserNotifications.framework !!