# RequestAuthorization for push outside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10

For ios 10 i used this for registering the push notifications :

[Registering for Push Notifications in Xcode 8/Swift 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956482/registering-for-push-notifications-in-xcode-8-swift-3-0/40407182#40407182)

Is there a way to ask for the requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) outside the appdelegate and the func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool

The reason i ask is because i don't want to present the pop up for push notifications after the user has used the app for a bit. Any ideas?

Comment: You can call it wherever you want

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like @dan said it isn't necessary to request the notifications permission in the `AppDelegate`. You can do it wherever you want to. This is what you probably be doing for that.

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (success, error) in
    if error == nil {
        if success {
            print("Permission granted")
            // In case you want to register for the remote notifications
            let application = UIApplication.shared
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        } else {
            print("Permission denied")
        }
    } else {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

**And Remember**

1. to import the `UserNotifications` framework where you use this code.
2. if you register for remote notifications you need to implement the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method in your `AppDelegate`

Comment: But before asking for user Authorization, can I call `UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()` to get the token first? Or I have to wait after the user authorized?

Comment: @NeoWang this method actually initiates the permissions request if the user hasn’t granted already. And remember without the permission you do not get the device token.

Comment: I think device token is thrown to app before the user grant the permission

Comment: @NeoWang Yes you can call. check the sample app from apple https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/implementing_alert_push_notifications

Answer (score 4):

The question for me is the pop up won't show again once user agreed or denied it. 
So we have to redirect users to Settings after that **manually**.

Here comes the code in Swift:

```
@IBAction func userDidClickButton(_ sender: Any) {

    // initialise a pop up for using later
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "TITLE", message: "Please go to Settings and turn on the permissions", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default) { (_) -> Void in
        guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) else {
            return
        }
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
            // do something
            }
         }
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addAction(settingsAction)

    // check the permission status
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings () { settings in            
        switch settings.authorizationStatus {
        case .denied, .notDetermined:
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        case .authorized:
            // continue the stuff
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                // Update UI
            }
        }
    }
}
```