# Application crash when adhoc distribute but doesn't crash when install with XCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash-reports

I have an Application and when ever i install the app via itunes/Diawi adhoc distribution it crashes but doesn't crash when i install the app via XCODE.

MY CRASH REPORT..

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   Vabo                            0x00000001000bb07c specialized AppDelegate.registerDeviceForPushNotification(UIApplication) -> () (AppDelegate.swift:214)
1   Vabo                            0x00000001000ab260 ViewController.(connectToWebWith(String, password : String) -> ()).(closure #2).(closure #3) (ViewController.swift:265)
```

> Swift method of Crash number 1:

```
func registerDeviceForPushNotification(application:UIApplication) -> Void {

        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.init(forTypes: [.Alert,.Badge,.Sound], categories: nil)
        self.pushNotificationToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!
        let userID = self.userData["id"] as! NSNumber

        print("InstanceID token: \(self.pushNotificationToken)")
        self.registerDeviceOnServerWith(self.pushNotificationToken, userID: userID)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }


func registerDeviceOnServerWith(token:String, userID:NSNumber) -> Void {
        let params = ["api_token":token, "user_id":userID , "type":"iOS"]

        //        params.setValue(username, forKey: "email")
        //        params.setValue(password, forKey: "password")
        let urlString = Constants.kMainURL + Constants.kRegisterDeviceToken;
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        do {
            request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: .PrettyPrinted)
        } catch {


            //handle error. Probably return or mark function as throws
            print(error)
            return
        }
        request.addValue(self.tokenID as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "token")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            // handle error
            guard error == nil else {

                return
            }

            print("Response: \(response)")
            let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Body: \(strData)")

            let json: NSDictionary?
            do {
                json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary
            } catch let dataError {
                // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
                print(dataError)
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
                // return or throw?
                return
            }

            // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still
            // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.
            if let parseJSON = json {
                // Okay, the parsedJSON is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it
                let success:NSString = (parseJSON["status"] as? NSString)!
                if success.isEqualToString("Success"){
                    print("APNS is Registeration is : \(success)")


                }else{

                    self.registerDeviceOnServerWith(token, userID: userID)
                    // Status Failed

                }

            }
            else {
                // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?

            }

        })

        task.resume()
    }
```

Method of Crash Number 2:

```
func connectToWebWith(username:String, password:String) -> Void {
        self.startLoadingAnimator()
        let params = ["email":username, "password":password]

//        params.setValue(username, forKey: "email")
//        params.setValue(password, forKey: "password")
        let urlString = Constants.kMainURL + Constants.kSignInURL;
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        do {
            request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: .PrettyPrinted)
        } catch {


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.stopLoadingAnimator()
                let alertView = UIAlertView.init(title: "Error", message: "Failed to authenticate", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alertView.show()


            })
            //handle error. Probably return or mark function as throws
            print(error)
            return
        }
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            // handle error
            guard error == nil else {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    self.stopLoadingAnimator()
                    let alertView = UIAlertView.init(title: "Error", message: "Couldn't establish connection", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                    alertView.show()


                })
                return
            }

            print("Response: \(response)")

            let json: NSDictionary?
            do {
                json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary
            } catch let dataError {
                // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
                print(dataError)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    self.stopLoadingAnimator()
                    let alertView = UIAlertView.init(title: "Error", message: "Failed to authenticate", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                    alertView.show()


                })
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
                // return or throw?
                return
            }

            self.stopLoadingAnimator()
            // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still
            // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.
            if let parseJSON = json {
                print("JSON = \(parseJSON)")
                // Okay, the parsedJSON is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it
                let success:NSString = (parseJSON["status"] as? NSString)!
                if success.isEqualToString("Success"){
                    print("Succes: \(success)")
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                            let userDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                            userDefault.setValue(username, forKey: Constants.kVaboEmail)
                            userDefault.synchronize()
                            userDefault.setValue(password, forKey: Constants.kVaboPassword)
                            userDefault.synchronize()
                            userDefault.setBool(true, forKey: Constants.kIsLoggedIn)
                            userDefault.synchronize()
                            let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
                            appDelegate.tokenID = (parseJSON["token"] as? NSString)!
                            let array = parseJSON["userData"] as! NSArray
                            appDelegate.userData = array.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSDictionary
                            appDelegate.userDidLoggedIn()


                    })
                }else{
                    let errorString = parseJSON["messageData"] as! String
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        let alertView = UIAlertView.init(title: "Vabo", message: errorString, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Dismiss")
                        alertView.show()

                    })


                }

            }
            else {
                // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    self.stopLoadingAnimator()
                    let alertView = UIAlertView.init(title: "Error", message: "Server Response Failed", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                    alertView.show()


                })
            }

        })

        task.resume()
    }
```

> P.S
>   The iPhone on the app give crash has iOS 10.1, 
>   While it runs perfectly on iOS 9.3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the log you provided it's not clear which line is the 214th. (AppDelegate.swift:214) and the reason for the crash is also missing from the log.

But I see you are using force cast a couple of places, I would make sure that those values actually exist when you try to access them. I suggest to use guard statements instead of force casting:

```
func registerDeviceForPushNotification(application:UIApplication) -> Void {

   let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.init(forTypes: [.Alert,.Badge,.Sound], categories: nil)

   guard let token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token(), let userID = self.userData["id"] as? NSNumber {
    // You might want to log something here
    return
   }

   print("InstanceID token: \(self.pushNotificationToken)")
   self.registerDeviceOnServerWith(self.pushNotificationToken, userID: userID)
   application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
   application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

**Update**:

If you take a look on the documentation of the UIUserNotificationSettings you can see it has been deprecated in iOS 10. You should use the UNUserNotificationCenter on iOS 10:

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter()
center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
    }
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956482/registering-for-push-notifications-in-xcode-8-swift-3-0) and [here](https://swifting.io/blog/2016/08/22/23-notifications-in-ios-10/)

Comment: Sorry...
Here is the 214th line in App Delegate
let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.init(forTypes: [.Alert,.Badge,.Sound], categories: nil)

Comment: Does this app crashes due to generating build from Xcode 7.3 and then trying to run it on iOS 10??
Because this app run perfectly without anycrash on iOS 9.3.5

Comment: While Line number 265 is the closing brackets of dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {


// This is the line number 264 in ViewController.swift -> })

Comment: Is this swift 2.2 code?
If yes then how can we run swift 2.2 code in Xcode 8?

Comment: You have to use UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter()

Comment: And what would be the second possible crash solution??