# remote notification issue swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notifications, push

I have an app that receives push notification but I have a doubt:

when app is in foreground and comes a remote notification I handle it but this method in AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

but I don't understand how do I have to handle the remote notification when comes a remote notification when app is in background and the user tap on rectangle of notification and then app opens.

Comment: se this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10/39383027#39383027

Comment: try this answer for swift 3.0 push notification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956482/registering-for-push-notifications-in-xcode-8-swift-3-0