# Push notification banner not at all coming even when app is in background in iOS with Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, push-notification, swift3

Push notification banner not at all coming even when app is in background in iOS - Swift 3.0. I followed following link to implement push notification for my app.

[Registering for Push Notifications in Xcode 8/Swift 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956482/registering-for-push-notifications-in-xcode-8-swift-3-0)

Comment: Can you share the APNs payload?

Comment: is your app making use of expiration handler ??

Comment: Make sure you have enabled Push Notification for the app. Also double check If you are using proper push notification certificate or not.

Comment: @ milanpanchal , The push notification is enabled already, and have proper push notification certificate also.

Comment: @Sandeep Bhandari . Not using any expiration handler.

Comment: payload =     {
        "merchant_id" = 266;
        "merchant_image" = "http://xxxxxx";
        "merchant_name" = "hello";
        message = "abcd";

Answer (score 0):

I found them unreliable as well when I had the device connected to Xcode.
Try removing and installing the app again, and then disconnect it from Xcode. It should start showing up after that when it enters background but, it's definitely not that reliable.

Hope that helps.

Kind regards,
Mukund

Comment: I tried removing and installing the app again, and then disconnect it from Xcode. But the issue still exists. Only sound and badge are coming. No banner is coming.

Comment: Any other settings issue?

Comment: Does it have banner enabled in the app's settings page?https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/iOS/ios10-iphone6-settings-notifications-messages.jpg

Comment: Finally solved it. The "alert" keyword value in the userInfo was coming as a Dictionary from server. When "alert" keyword is changed to string,(at server side) Banner started appearing. Thanks for all comments.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it.
The "alert" keyword value in the userInfo was coming as a Dictionary from server. When "alert" keyword is changed to string,(at server side) Banner started appearing. Thanks for all comments.

Comment: Can you paste your payload, please?

Comment: @ScottyBlades I wish I could. But I am not having access to that code now, as I have joined another company.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Don't forget to make sure your phone is not in "DO NOT DISTURB" mode.