# Getting empty device token in iPhone 5 and iPhone SE

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, push-notification, swift2

I am not getting device token in iPhone 5 (10.2.1) and SE(10.3.1) and other 5 related devices but successfully getting tokens in all iPhone 6 (including plus, SE) and 7, and 7+ also.

This is my code for registering

```
func registerForPushNotification(let application: UIApplication) {
    let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
    let pushNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotificationSettings)

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

    if pushNotificationSettings.types != .None {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}
```

And this is my code for collecting token

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

    let characterSet: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet( charactersInString: "<>" )
    let deviceTokenString: String = ( deviceToken.description as NSString )
        .stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet( characterSet )
        .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( " ", withString: "" ) as String
    print( deviceTokenString )
}
```

Any help?

Comment: remove app from device and install again .

Comment: see requestAuthorization in this   http://stackoverflow.com/a/37967012/3901620

Comment: Is their OS version differs?

Comment: @BalajiGalave In 6, my os is 10.1.1 which runs successfully but in 5, os is 10.2.1 which returns empty

Comment: have you implemented `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings` ?

Comment: @Lion nope, i have implemented `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: in which mode are you running application in all the device ?

Comment: implement `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings` and in this method register for remote notification again!

Comment: With the same code of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` ? @Lion

Comment: yeah! this method returns settings allows by users, so you should implement it! In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` you register for settings that you want but this method returns settings that user have changed from setting app! you should do like  : if notificationSettings.types != [] {
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }   Refer [Raywenderlich tutorial for reference](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial)

Comment: for getting device token         `let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})`
this code is  better , isn't it @Lion

Comment: @MikeAlter : it is good but nothing wrong in OP's code also!

Comment: @Lion not working

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi : this can be issue of `APNS` also for respective ios version! Have you print `deviceToken` before doing any operation on it ? i mean check that you are getting token (NSData) or not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have handled `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings` in my `AppDelegate`

Like this

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
    if notificationSettings.types != [] {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }   
}
```

This solved the issue which was suggested by  @Lion

Comment: You mean you only changed from `.None` to `[]` and your problem was solved?!

Comment: I didn't handle `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings` previously. After handling this, my problem solved @Honey