# How to Receive Push Notifications in Foreground iOS Swift 3.0?

Tags: swift3, ios8, apple-push-notifications

I want to display Push Notifications in Foreground State for `iOS 8.0`. I'm receiving notifications in background state, but not in foreground state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Registering for Push Notifications in Xcode 8/Swift 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956482/registering-for-push-notifications-in-xcode-8-swift-3-0)

Comment: @Hexfire I want to display Push Notifications in Foreground State for iOS 8.0,i m receiving notifications in background state

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get push notification while App in foreground iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872088/get-push-notification-while-app-in-foreground-ios)

Comment: @Hexfire That's for +iOS10. This question is for iOS8. So you got the wrong question. It's duplicate of *another* question

Comment: have you got any solutions? I'm facing this problem too

Comment: @Frank still searching for solutions

Answer (score 1):

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert)

        //completionHandler([.alert,.badge])
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {

        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        completionHandler([])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response:UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

Comment: completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert) is what you need.

Comment: that's for iOS10. The question is about iOS 8. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872088/get-push-notification-while-app-in-foreground-ios)

Comment: @Honey could u tell me how will i do as per my code

Comment: @CtanLi als because  i already getting notifications in iOS 10 in foreground i want in iOS 8