# IOS App doesn't get notification data when minimized

Tags: ios

When app is in background mode and it gets a push notification.. and if we open the app we don't get any response from push

Steps to followup

- we have minimize the app then we got a push with some data from backend.
- After that if we open the app we don't get any data received from the push that we got when app is in minimized mode.
- But we get a badge notification on the app.

Note:- Stil we are using Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: You won't receive push notifications when the application is in the foreground, if that's what you're asking.  And this would be a duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872088/get-push-notification-while-app-in-foreground-ios

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get push notification while App in foreground iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872088/get-push-notification-while-app-in-foreground-ios)