# Notification not triggered when app in foreground - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, push-notification

I'm using firebase to implement push notifications in iOS, with objective c.
I have the method `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler`, which should be triggered when the app is in background and the user taps the notification and also when the app is in foreground, according to its description. Thing is it only works in background (or when the app is no running).
Am I forgetting something?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Even though its [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872088/get-push-notification-while-app-in-foreground-ios?rq=1) question here is a solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/40756206/3632832

Comment: yes it won't trigger when you are in foreground, you have to handle that on your own like showing it in alert in iOS less than 10 and above 10 you have a custom delegate method to handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS 10 and above below method is called when application is in foreground:

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler
```

So you need to observe this method to handle notification while app is in foreground

Comment: I know it's closed but is there any way to get the info of the notification? I mean, in didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler you have a nsdictionary (userinfo) with the parameters of the notification.

Comment: @JaimeAlcántaraArnela yes, you can get same dictionary by notification.userInfo in userNotificationCenter: willPresentNotification: withCompletionHandler method

If it is what you are looking for then pls upvote my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks @vivek, that's what I needed.

Comment: if my answers helps you then dont forget to upvote my answer @JaimeAlcántaraArnela

Answer (score 3):

You can use this below code:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
        UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
        if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
            {
                //app is in foreground
                //the push is in your control
                UILocalNotification *localNotification = 
               [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
               localNotification.userInfo = userInfo;
               localNotification.soundName = 
               UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
               localNotification.alertBody = message;
               localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
               scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
            }
            else
            {
               //app is in background:
               //iOS is responsible for displaying push alerts, banner etc..
            }
        }
```

Comment: message is not defined. where do you get it?

Answer (score 1):

The standart example for iOS Firebase Notifications is implemented in AppDelegate like `completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);`

If you like in foreground you have to implemt it.

Comment: Because standard setup is that the notification links to your app.

Comment: nice advise but how? can you please explain more?