# How to trigger an action once the push notification banner is clicked on foreground

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, push-notification

As of now i get the push notifications and displaying the banner when im in both foreground and background states. But though its works fine in the background, when I'm in foreground im unable to trigger an action to open a specific view controller once i click the banner (should open only if i click the banner). How would i do this. My code as bellow

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
    {

        print("Recived: \(userInfo)")

        completionHandler(.newData)


        if state == .background {
            if mediaId != nil{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    let mP3ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"MP3ViewController") as! MP3ViewController
                    mP3ViewController.media_ID = mediaId
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mP3ViewController, animated:true)

                }

            }
        }else if state == .active {
      //What sould i do here to get the click 

            print("Running on foreground")
            UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
            let count = 0
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(count, forKey: "PUSH_COUNT")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()


        }

    }
```

Comment: if app is open push notificaiton banner wont show. as you need to use custom banner that show push notification when app on forgrond and you can get its click event

Comment: in foreground whenever you got notification you have to dismiss all viewcontrollers from navigationcontroller and then try to push your desire one controller @danu

Comment: with the code above it woks fine with displaying the banner, no need to create a custom. but having troubles of triggering the click event

Comment: yeah as @NitinGohel mentioned you will not get banner notification if your app is in foreground , but you will get the callback of didreceiveremotnotification

Comment: public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Swift.Void) {
        completionHandler([.badge, .alert, .sound])
      // This delegate will give my banner 
    }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get push notification while App in foreground iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872088/get-push-notification-while-app-in-foreground-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this 
Implement `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`  in your `AppDelegate` class

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
}
```

Add bellow method in `AppDelegate` class

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("didReceive response")
        completionHandler()
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("willPresent notification")

        completionHandler([.badge, .alert, .sound])
    }
```

Above method will call while push notification appear in foreground.

**Edit:-**

Add this method called by interactive notification delegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, for notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("identifier = \(identifier)")
    }
```

**Edit2 :**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], withResponseInfo responseInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("identifier = \(identifier)")
    }
```

Comment: I already have these two, but i wants to trigger the click action

Comment: didnt get u, u mean just to add this anywhere in AppDelegate ??

Comment: sir is there a way to get my no userInfo object in here

Comment: print("identifier = \(String(describing: identifier))") doesnt get triggered at all

Comment: aren't `handleActionWithIdentifier` methods deprecated?! They are replaced with the `didReceiveResponse` method...unless he's targeting less than iOS10