# Swift ios push notification notif not woking when app is open but its working when app is closed

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

How to handle push notif that it will notify even when the app is open or closed. i have the ff. code below and its notifying when app is close but it does not notify when app is open. i have provided my source code below.Thank You. Help greatly appreciated.How to handle push notif that it will notify even when the app is open or closed. i have the ff. code below and its notifying when app is close but it does not notify when app is open. i have provided my source code below.Thank You. Help greatly appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.


        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLoggedIn") {
            let  menuVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuCollectionViewController") as! MenuCollectionViewController

            let nvc: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: menuVC)
            nvc.navigationBar.isHidden =  true

            self.window?.rootViewController = nvc
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        } else {

           self.showLoginScreen()
        }

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        let notificationTypes : UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert , UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
        let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationTypes,categories : nil)

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

//        print("MessageID: \(userInfo["gcm_message_id"])")
//        print(userInfo)

        if let message = userInfo["gcm_message_id"] {
            print("MessageID: \(message)")
        }
        print(userInfo)

    }

    func showLoginScreen()
    {

        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isLoggedIn")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()


        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let loginViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController

        let nvc: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginViewController)
        nvc.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        self.window?.rootViewController = nvc
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }


    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "FridgeBoard")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {

                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()


    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {

                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: check this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872088/get-push-notification-while-app-in-foreground-ios

Comment: it's not suitable for you, to collect the answer from others then answer your own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
```

use below code

```
[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

                let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                    options: authOptions,
                    completionHandler: {_, _ in })
            } else {
                let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                    UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
                application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            }
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code

```
       @UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }



   @available(iOS 10, *)

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
     Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // print(userInfo)
      completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
   // completionHandler([])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    switch response.actionIdentifier {
    case "action1":
        print("Action First Tapped")
    case "action2":
        print("Action Second Tapped")
    default:
        break
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    completionHandler()
}
```

}

Comment: Thank You sir ill try it

Comment: let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

Comment: i have tried i cant still receive push notif when app is open

Comment: Which ios version you will check

Comment: what do you mean Sir?

Comment: post above code in Appdelegate-> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions  Method

Comment: im still on fixing it i have recieved 9 errors from adding the code

Comment: import UserNotifications

Comment: done importing i have replaced  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self to UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate , still not getting notif when app is open

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Okey now check my code i will changes please update this

Comment: btw i am testing the app on an ipad,

Comment: can you please update it joined with my example above? Sir.

Comment: i am having trouble combining it.

Comment: where is the problem

Comment: Btw sir , i would just like to ask if how to trigger push notif inside the app like by clicking the button instead of sending message through firebase console. is that possible Sir?

Comment: is badge hard to create sir whenver you receive a push notif

Answer (score 0):

implement below method at app delegate:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert)
}
```