# Firebase Cloud Messaging Integrate with iOS App - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

[image]

I have a barebone ios app, that I'm trying to integrate with FireBase Cloud Messaging.

## I've tried

**Apple Developer Portal**

I already enabled Push Notification on my App ID  (`com.bunlongheng.APNS`) .

[image]

---

**Firebase console**

I created a project,
I created an app,
I gave the bundle ID as my app (`com.bunlongheng.APNS`).
I also went to the `app` > `settings` > `Cloud Messaging` > and upload my APNS key.

[image]

---

**XCode**

I created a pod file with this content

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'APNS' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for APNS
  pod 'Firebase/Core'

end
```

then run pod install.

I downloaded and added the `GoogleService-Info.plist` into my ios app root directory.

I enabled **Push Notification** compatibility

[image]

**Background Mode**

[image]

I compiled them onto my iPhone.

## Attempting to trigger a push notification.

**Firebase console**

I went to Cloud Messaging and tested my first message experiment.

[image]

I see a `success` message on the Firebase, but I still don't see anything triggering into my iPhone after I **allow** the permission for Notification.

[image]

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
//
//  Copyright (c) 2016 Google Inc.
//
//  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
//  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
//  You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
//  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
//  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
//  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
//  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
//  limitations under the License.
//

import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        // [START set_messaging_delegate]
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        // [END set_messaging_delegate]
        // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
        // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        
        // [END register_for_notifications]
        return true
    }
    
    // [START receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    // [END receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
    // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
    // the FCM registration token.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")
        
        // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
        // Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        
        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
    }
    
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    // [START refresh_token]
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
        
        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
        
        print(fcmToken)
    }
    // [END refresh_token]
    // [START ios_10_data_message]
    // Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
    // To enable direct data messages, you can set Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
    // [END ios_10_data_message]
}
```

How would one go about debugging this further?

Answer (score 1):

You may miss `registerForRemoteNotifications`

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

  let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
    options: authOptions,
    completionHandler: {_, _ in })
} else {
  let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
  UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
  application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}

application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

To see the alert even in foreground

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
    extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate { 
        // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) { 
      completionHandler([.alert, .sound])  
}

}
```

And this called in background also

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], 
    fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

You should follow all the steps [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)

Comment: do u have other suggestion ?

Comment: make sure you set the .p12 key in firebase to match it's development / distribution certificate

Comment: I login to my developer portal > App ID, and make sure to enabled these : https://i.imgur.com/qYXAse1.png

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you actually need to implement a message handling function, that will get called when the message arrives:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
  // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
  // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
  // TODO: Handle data of notification


  // Print full message.
  print(userInfo)
}
```

Also, there are a couple of variations on the handling function that you may want to try

Comment: How do I see the actual alert on my phone rather than just printing it ?

Comment: I think that's a permission thing, when you register to receive notifications with the alert, badge and sound , basically, if you allow them they are shown and the handling code "notifies you"

Comment: aha, with the handling code? and it gets called but you don't see the notification?

Comment: yes, with the handling code added to my AppDelegate.swift : https://i.imgur.com/WOcDjSc.png

Comment: This is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872088/get-push-notification-while-app-in-foreground-ios

Comment: Try that not helping at all.. same result.

Comment: Hey, do you think this has something to do with my certificate? We need to **enabled** certain features to make it work ?

Comment: On both firebase and apple portals you have to enable the permissions yes. In the Apple site I think it's app id's

Comment: I did already, I listed all the steps in my post. Can you see if I missed anything else ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184346/discussion-between-sergio-flores-and-kyo).